# How to transfer the excel file to database access using vb.net?

Tags: .net, excel, vb.net, ms-access

i have 3 button that is use to transfer the data from excell file to acces database., this is the interface of the windows form

[image]

the **first** button is use to open dialog openfile to select the file exel

the **second** is use to open the excel file and store to the datatable.

and the **third** button is use to transfer the excel data to access.

this is the code of

**first button**

```
Private Sub cmdGetExcel_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles cmdGetExcel.Click
        Try
            Dim fd As OpenFileDialog = New OpenFileDialog()
            Dim strFileName As String

            fd.Title = "Open File Dialog"
            fd.InitialDirectory = "C:\"
            fd.Filter = "Excel files(*.xls)|*.xls"
            fd.FilterIndex = 2
            fd.RestoreDirectory = True


            If fd.ShowDialog() = DialogResult.OK Then
                strFileName = fd.FileName
                path = fd.FileName
                Text1.Text = path

            Else



            End If

        Catch ex As Exception
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message)
        End Try

    End Sub
```

this is a code of
**second button**

```
 Private Sub OpenDatabase_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles OpenDatabase.Click
        Try

            Dim connectexcelstring As String = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source='" & Text1.Text & "';" & _
                 "Extended Properties=""Excel 8.0;HDR=yes"""
            Dim con As OleDbConnection = New OleDbConnection(connectexcelstring)

            con.Open()

            Dim query As String = "Select * from [Sheet1$]"

            Dim excelcmd As OleDbCommand = New OleDbCommand(query, con)


            dt.Load(excelcmd.ExecuteReader())

            Dim rowData As String = ""
            Dim i = 0

            For Each row As DataRow In dt.Rows
                For Each column As DataColumn In dt.Columns()
                    rowData = rowData & column.ColumnName & "=" & row(column) & " "
                Next
                rowData = rowData & vbNewLine & vbNewLine
            Next



            MessageBox.Show(rowData)

            MsgBox("Destination Database has been open")

        Catch ex As Exception

            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message)
        End Try
    End Sub
```

this is the **third** button , (the transfer button)

```
 Private Sub TransferExcelFile2Database_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles TransferExcelFile2Database.Click

    End Sub
```

im not have idea how to transfer the excel file in transfer button ,,

any idea?

Comment: Do you have to insert the file as a BLOB into the database or you have to read the file row by row and insert its content into the database?

Comment: @sam how to insert file as BlOB ?

Comment: @sam read row by row using ?

Comment: It's unclear what you mean by transfer: if you mean import the whole file your question, at least, could be answered but if you want to read the data row by row and insert it in the db, then, this task can be rather complex based on the format of your file and the structure of the db.